# SQL statement with conditionals

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm currently building a food application which has users select a range of options (perishable, non-perishable ) and (snack, produce or meal) via a set of radio buttons. I'm currently using node.js and sqlite 3 to query a database to determine which entries to return to the user after they search the database.

I want to write a query such that when the booleans from the client-side are sent over to the server, the server will choose the entries such that perishable if perishable is set to true on the client that the query will find just the perishable items and vice-versa. I also want the same functionality with

Example:

```
perishable = request.perishable.
non-perishable = request.non-perishable
snack = request.non-perishable
meal = request.non-perishable
produce = request.non-perishable.

var q = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE available == true AND (if perishable is true all rows where the perishable column is set to true... etc );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the query based on `perishable`?

```
var q = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE available == true';
if (perishable)
    q += ' AND perishable == true';
```

Comment: Might be better to update query to always include perishable but change the value based on the request. Otherwise with the way you currently have it, if perishable is false in the request, the query will also return rows where perishable is true.

Comment: @Sasang That's what I was initially writing, but then I realized the OP doesn't say what to do when `perishable` is not true. I assumed he still wanted all the data if `perishable` was false. But I agree it would be easiest to just do `var q = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE available == true  AND perishable == ' + perishable;` if that is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a CASE WHEN syntax in WHERE:

```
WHERE perishable IS CASE WHEN [condition] THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

Just a quick tip. Search for this syntax in your database documentation.